How to make uneditable layers editable in ArcGIS Pro
I am new to ArcGIS Pro and GIS in general. I am trying to copy data from a map layer onto other layers. However, the desired destination layers are not editable, so I am unable to copy data onto them. How can I make the destination layers editable?

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Unfortunately, is'd difficult to answer your Question without knowing WHY the layer is not editable. Is it because the file share is read-only?  Because it's in a database? Because it's in a format that doesn't support editing?  Generally speaking, the layers are read-only for a reason, so you really ought to be talking to the person who has that reason.

You can toggle on editing for the layer being pasted to.
Have you checked the official help guides:
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/specify-which-layers-can-be-edited.htm

To turn edibility on or off for one or more layers, complete the
following steps:
On the View ribbon tab, click Contents Contents in the Windows group.
The Contents pane appears.
Click the List By Editing tab List By Editing. Contents pane Uncheck a
layer check box to turn off editability for the layer. Check the layer
check box to turn on editability.

